# Can you set up Bitvise (Windows Server) to run a script when a specific file is transferred?

Tags: windows, batch, windows-server-2016, bitvise

I have set up Bitvise (v 7.3) in a Windows Server 2016 box. I can connect and transfer files via SFTP to the server from my local computer using WinSCP and a custom command-line application.

I would like to run a script (to copy the transferred file to different locations and then delete it) when the file arrives. Is it possible to set up Bitvise to run that script on file arrival? I do not want the client to run the script. The requirement is to have the server check the arrival of the file and proceed accordingly.

I've been searching Bitvise documentation and cannot find a way to accomplish this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a comment, but if Bitvise doesn't support this kind of thing, there are certainly small utilities that can watch a folder (or folders) and run necessary scripts accordingly.

Comment: @PapaCcompis Are you opposed to a non-Bitvise Windows native solution on the server that will move the file when files arrive into the folder? If so, can you tell me if you are moving all files if files arrive or just files with specific names as they arrive regardless of other files that get transferred to the same folder? Are you opposed to a scripted process that's not BitVise but Windows native that checks every x minutes or do you want something that actively monitors and does the action on arrival? I have some ideas and logic I've used before that I'll share depending on your response.

Comment: @Pimp Juice IT, thanks for commenting. The company I work for has a set of approved software and applications that we could use. I think we could easily use Windows Server native components/tools. Having said that, we do use Autosys as a default scheduler for most of out batch jobs. If Bitvise doesn't have this functionality, we will opt for using Autosys. I just thought that it was worth it exploring a Bitvise based solution, since the files will arrive via SFTP. Thanks again!